После 10 секунд бот выключает песню и молчит
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот готов к работе")


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("Вы должны быть подключены к голосовому каналу, чтобы использовать эту команду.")
        return

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        filename = ydl.prepare_filename(info)

    voice_client = await channel.connect()

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename))
    await ctx.send(f"Сейчас играет: {info['title']}")

    
    duration = info.get('duration', 0)
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    await voice_client.disconnect()


@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    await voice_client.disconnect()

бот отключается с текстом якобы все в порядке " discord.player: ffmpeg process 1736 successfully terminated with return code of 0."

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести. «У меня программа не работает, хотя вот тут такой же код работает нормально». Прежде чем задавать вопрос, убедитесь на минимальном примере(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), что проблема не в банальной опечатке. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
и настоятельно рекомендуем ознакомиться со справкой как задать хороший вопрос ===> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Добавьте к вызову метода discord.FFmpegPCMAudio второй аргумент с опциями:
discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options)
А сами опции должны быть такими:
ffmpeg_options = {
    "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5 -nostdin",
    "options": "-vn",
}

Это позволит поддерживать постоянное соединение и не прерывать поток.

Попробуйте использовать FFmpegOpusAudio:
fpg_opt = {"before_options":"-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 100", "options":"-vn"}
voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(source=source, bitrate=320, **fpg_opt))

На своём опыте проверил, что FFmpegOpusAudio лучше FFmpegPCMAudio в плане качества воспроизведения. Если не сработает, напишите в комментарии, постараюсь быстро ответить.
